# Why didn't Netero use vows and limitations like Kurapika?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Why didn't Netero use a limitation and vow like Kurapika to beat Meruem? Kurapika was able to chain the Phantom Troops by making a vow that she would only use the chains on the Phantom Troops or else she would die. Why didn't netero do something similar?

Comment: I don't know if i am conveying my question properly i don't understand half of the show so i  don't want to go on with so much confusion so someone please help

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, one can't just *add* a Limitation or a Vow to an ability.

Specifics of developing a Nen ability are left a bit vague in the story, but it's rather clear that Vows and Limitations are inherent part of each ability that are added to them as they are created. And since Netero didn't create any *new* abilities to fight Meruem, those would have needed to be already present.

Also, most hunters dislike adding Limitations to abilities. The enhancement of power they provide is inconsistent and the conditions need to be very severe for the benefit to be significant. Kurapika is able to use as severe Vows as he does because hunting the Phantom Troops is *literally* his life's work. He's willing to sacrifice a lot of the general power of his abilities to make them *really* powerful in specific situations.

Now, there is one powerup that Netero could have perhaps used. General emotion of risk. This is sort of the basis of where Limitations and Vows get their power in the first place, but more primal. It is the risks that Limitations impose that give them their power and it is possible tap into the same source without imposing a formal Limitation. Shoot used this when he covered one of his eyes while fighting Youpi, sort of imposing a temporary limitation on himself. It could also be argued that Gon's Jajanken gets a bit of a powerup from the risk that its long windup and general vulnerability present.

Of course, Netero was already going to fight possibly the strongest living being on in the known world, so I'm not sure how much of an extra risk there could be.

Side note: I haven't read the Dark Continent Expedition arc or the Succession Contest arc, so if there are any exceptions to these, they'd be there.

Answer (score 1):

Netero didn't need to use limitation and vow to beat meruem. Once Netero figured out his attacks were barely leaving a scratch on meruem he used his most powerful attack Miniature Rose Bomb.

Comment: Can you explain why netero didn't need to use limitation because it would have made him stronger and t's a better option than blowing everything up right ? Wouldn't limitation grand netero more power and stricter the limitation the more powerful right? Kurapika was able to overpower phantom troops with limitation and using her Scarlett eyes wouldn't netero be benafited the same way with his ability along with a really strict restriction.

Comment: Well, it could be just because he didn't want to. In other words he probably thought he didn't need limitation or vows and that he was already strong enough without limitation. But, in the end he did win after all

Comment: Well wouldn't it be reasonable way to go after he finds meruem is stronger i mean kurapika is able to overpower people on the level of phantom troop so it doesn't make sense why netero never considered that option when he finds meruem is  way stronger than be a coward and setting off a neuclear bomb well thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

Netero had been alive for a long time. This was the first fight in a long time where he was actually going to go up against a worthy opponent. As others said previously limitations/vows can’t really be created after the ability has been conceived except in  cases like with shoot.

The only thing that Netero could have possibly utilized in the form of a vow/limitation is some form of Post Mortem Nen. But it is entirely possible that even that might not have worked because he technically already had a Post Mortem ability in the form of the miniature rose, and knowing that he had that, he might not have been able to generate a conviction strong enough to go off after he died